# trying all combinations of operations on list of variables

Tags: python, combinations

I have a list of values like:

```
values = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

and I want to try all combinations on this list like:

```
1 + 2
1 + 3
1 + 4
1 * 2
1 * 3
1 * 4
1 + 2 * 3
1 + 2 * 4
1 + 3 * 4
```

etc.

What would be the most straightforward way to get all these possible combinations of operations in the most succinct way possible?

I would imagine having two lists, [1,2,3,4] and [+, *, -, /] and then taking all combinations of the numbers of all lengths, and then filling in the blanks with all combinations.

So selecting [1, 2, 3] and then selecting all permutations of the operations and combining them together.  This seems messy and I'm hoping there's a clearer way to code this?

Comment: can you show us what you attempted to do?

Comment: I recommend [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html). First, choose 2-4 among 4 numbers. Second, permutate them. Third, choose 1-3 among 4 operators. Fourth, permeate them. Fifth, take a number, an operator, a number, an operator, and so on.

Comment: Your suggested solution is the simplest and most straightforward way to do it.

Comment: Do you want to have the *results* or the expressions in some form?  In any case a recursive solution seems easy. When you have exactly two input values you just call all possible operations with those arguments, when you have more than 2 inputs you take one input, you recursively find all combinations of the remaining inputs and operations and then you apply all operations to the input you excluded and all possible results you obtained from the recursive call.

Comment: I like the recursive solution, that's actually a pretty great idea

Comment: What about precedence? For example, do you want `1+2*3` and `(1+2)*3`

Comment: Is `1 + 2 + 3` a valid result set? `+` twice

Comment: Added cleaner code without using `eval` as using eval is bad practice and is quite insecure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a recursive solution that builds the expression from numbers & operators and then uses [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#eval) to calculate it:

```
vals = [1, 2, 3]
operators = ['+', '*', '-', '/']

def expressions(values):
    # Base case, only one value left
    if len(values) == 1:
        yield values

    # Iterate over the indexes
    for i in range(len(values)):
        # Pop value from given index and store the remaining values
        # to be used with next recursion
        forward = values[:]
        val = forward.pop(i)

        # Yield all value, operator, subexpression combinations
        for op in operators:
            for rest in expressions(forward):
                yield [val, op] + rest

for expr in expressions(vals):
    expr = ' '.join(str(x) for x in expr)
    print('{} = {}'.format(expr, eval(expr)))
```

Output (partial):

```
1 + 2 + 3 = 6
1 + 2 * 3 = 7
1 + 2 - 3 = 0
1 + 2 / 3 = 1.6666666666666665
1 + 3 + 2 = 6
1 + 3 * 2 = 7
1 + 3 - 2 = 2
1 + 3 / 2 = 2.5
1 * 2 + 3 = 5
1 * 2 * 3 = 6
1 * 2 - 3 = -1
1 * 2 / 3 = 0.6666666666666666
1 * 3 + 2 = 5
1 * 3 * 2 = 6
1 * 3 - 2 = 1
1 * 3 / 2 = 1.5
1 - 2 + 3 = 2
1 - 2 * 3 = -5
1 - 2 - 3 = -4
```

Comment: is there a simple way to change your function so that  `expressions` takes a second argument `operations`?

Comment: @DanielG Yes, just add second argument called `operations`, change iteration to happen over it `for op in operations` and change all the `expression` calls to pass the second argument. I just didn't see much point coding it in since the list of operations is fixed on every call.

Answer (score 2):

How about this one (since order of the operands and operators does matter, we must use permutation) ?

```
from itertools import chain, permutations

def powerset(iterable):
  xs = list(iterable)
  return chain.from_iterable(permutations(xs,n) for n in range(len(xs)+1) )

lst_expr = []
for operands in map(list, powerset(['1','2','3','4'])):
    n = len(operands)
    #print operands
    if n > 1:
        all_operators = map(list, permutations(['+','-','*','/'],n-1))
        #print all_operators, operands
        for operators in all_operators:
            exp = operands[0]
            i = 1
            for operator in operators:
                exp += operator + operands[i]
                i += 1
            lst_expr += [exp]

print ', '.join(lst_expr)
```

with the following output:

```
1+2, 1-2, 1*2, 1/2, 1+3, 1-3, 1*3, 1/3, 1+4, 1-4, 1*4, 1/4, 2+1, 2-1, 2*1, 2/1, 2+3, 2-3, 2*3, 2/3, 2+4, 2-4, 2*4, 2/4, 3+1, 3-1, 3*1, 3/1, 3+2, 3-2, 3*2, 3/2, 3+4, 3-4, 3*4, 3/4, 4+1, 4-1, 4*1, 4/1, 4+2, 4-2, 4*2, 4/2, 4+3, 4-3, 4*3, 4/3, 1+2-3, 1+2*3, 1+2/3, 1-2+3, 1-2*3, 1-2/3, 1*2+3, 1*2-3, 1*2/3, 1/2+3, 1/2-3, 1/2*3, 1+2-4, 1+2*4, 1+2/4, 1-2+4, 1-2*4, 1-2/4, 1*2+4, 1*2-4, 1*2/4, 1/2+4, 1/2-4, 1/2*4, 1+3-2, 1+3*2, 1+3/2, 1-3+2, 1-3*2, 1-3/2, 1*3+2, 1*3-2, 1*3/2, 1/3+2, 1/3-2, 1/3*2, 1+3-4, 1+3*4, 1+3/4, 1-3+4, 1-3*4, 1-3/4, 1*3+4, 1*3-4, 1*3/4, 1/3+4, 1/3-4, 1/3*4, 1+4-2, 1+4*2, 1+4/2, 1-4+2, 1-4*2, 1-4/2, 1*4+2, 1*4-2, 1*4/2, 1/4+2, 1/4-2, 1/4*2, 1+4-3, 1+4*3, 1+4/3, 1-4+3, 1-4*3, 1-4/3, 1*4+3, 1*4-3, 1*4/3, 1/4+3, 1/4-3, 1/4*3, 2+1-3, 2+1*3, 2+1/3, 2-1+3, 2-1*3, 2-1/3, 2*1+3, 2*1-3, 2*1/3, 2/1+3, 2/1-3, 2/1*3, 2+1-4, 2+1*4, 2+1/4, 2-1+4, 2-1*4, 2-1/4, 2*1+4, 2*1-4, 2*1/4, 2/1+4, 2/1-4, 2/1*4, 2+3-1, 2+3*1, 2+3/1, 2-3+1, 2-3*1, 2-3/1, 2*3+1, 2*3-1, 2*3/1, 2/3+1, 2/3-1, 2/3*1, 2+3-4, 2+3*4, 2+3/4, 2-3+4, 2-3*4, 2-3/4, 2*3+4, 2*3-4, 2*3/4, 2/3+4, 2/3-4, 2/3*4, 2+4-1, 2+4*1, 2+4/1, 2-4+1, 2-4*1, 2-4/1, 2*4+1, 2*4-1, 2*4/1, 2/4+1, 2/4-1, 2/4*1, 2+4-3, 2+4*3, 2+4/3, 2-4+3, 2-4*3, 2-4/3, 2*4+3, 2*4-3, 2*4/3, 2/4+3, 2/4-3, 2/4*3, 3+1-2, 3+1*2, 3+1/2, 3-1+2, 3-1*2, 3-1/2, 3*1+2, 3*1-2, 3*1/2, 3/1+2, 3/1-2, 3/1*2, 3+1-4, 3+1*4, 3+1/4, 3-1+4, 3-1*4, 3-1/4, 3*1+4, 3*1-4, 3*1/4, 3/1+4, 3/1-4, 3/1*4, 3+2-1, 3+2*1, 3+2/1, 3-2+1, 3-2*1, 3-2/1, 3*2+1, 3*2-1, 3*2/1, 3/2+1, 3/2-1, 3/2*1, 3+2-4, 3+2*4, 3+2/4, 3-2+4, 3-2*4, 3-2/4, 3*2+4, 3*2-4, 3*2/4, 3/2+4, 3/2-4, 3/2*4, 3+4-1, 3+4*1, 3+4/1, 3-4+1, 3-4*1, 3-4/1, 3*4+1, 3*4-1, 3*4/1, 3/4+1, 3/4-1, 3/4*1, 3+4-2, 3+4*2, 3+4/2, 3-4+2, 3-4*2, 3-4/2, 3*4+2, 3*4-2, 3*4/2, 3/4+2, 3/4-2, 3/4*2, 4+1-2, 4+1*2, 4+1/2, 4-1+2, 4-1*2, 4-1/2, 4*1+2, 4*1-2, 4*1/2, 4/1+2, 4/1-2, 4/1*2, 4+1-3, 4+1*3, 4+1/3, 4-1+3, 4-1*3, 4-1/3, 4*1+3, 4*1-3, 4*1/3, 4/1+3, 4/1-3, 4/1*3, 4+2-1, 4+2*1, 4+2/1, 4-2+1, 4-2*1, 4-2/1, 4*2+1, 4*2-1, 4*2/1, 4/2+1, 4/2-1, 4/2*1, 4+2-3, 4+2*3, 4+2/3, 4-2+3, 4-2*3, 4-2/3, 4*2+3, 4*2-3, 4*2/3, 4/2+3, 4/2-3, 4/2*3, 4+3-1, 4+3*1, 4+3/1, 4-3+1, 4-3*1, 4-3/1, 4*3+1, 4*3-1, 4*3/1, 4/3+1, 4/3-1, 4/3*1, 4+3-2, 4+3*2, 4+3/2, 4-3+2, 4-3*2, 4-3/2, 4*3+2, 4*3-2, 4*3/2, 4/3+2, 4/3-2, 4/3*2, 1+2-3*4, 1+2-3/4, 1+2*3-4, 1+2*3/4, 1+2/3-4, 1+2/3*4, 1-2+3*4, 1-2+3/4, 1-2*3+4, 1-2*3/4, 1-2/3+4, 1-2/3*4, 1*2+3-4, 1*2+3/4, 1*2-3+4, 1*2-3/4, 1*2/3+4, 1*2/3-4, 1/2+3-4, 1/2+3*4, 1/2-3+4, 1/2-3*4, 1/2*3+4, 1/2*3-4, 1+2-4*3, 1+2-4/3, 1+2*4-3, 1+2*4/3, 1+2/4-3, 1+2/4*3, 1-2+4*3, 1-2+4/3, 1-2*4+3, 1-2*4/3, 1-2/4+3, 1-2/4*3, 1*2+4-3, 1*2+4/3, 1*2-4+3, 1*2-4/3, 1*2/4+3, 1*2/4-3, 1/2+4-3, 1/2+4*3, 1/2-4+3, 1/2-4*3, 1/2*4+3, 1/2*4-3, 1+3-2*4, 1+3-2/4, 1+3*2-4, 1+3*2/4, 1+3/2-4, 1+3/2*4, 1-3+2*4, 1-3+2/4, 1-3*2+4, 1-3*2/4, 1-3/2+4, 1-3/2*4, 1*3+2-4, 1*3+2/4, 1*3-2+4, 1*3-2/4, 1*3/2+4, 1*3/2-4, 1/3+2-4, 1/3+2*4, 1/3-2+4, 1/3-2*4, 1/3*2+4, 1/3*2-4, 1+3-4*2, 1+3-4/2, 1+3*4-2, 1+3*4/2, 1+3/4-2, 1+3/4*2, 1-3+4*2, 1-3+4/2, 1-3*4+2, 1-3*4/2, 1-3/4+2, 1-3/4*2, 1*3+4-2, 1*3+4/2, 1*3-4+2, 1*3-4/2, 1*3/4+2, 1*3/4-2, 1/3+4-2, 1/3+4*2, 1/3-4+2, 1/3-4*2, 1/3*4+2, 1/3*4-2, 1+4-2*3, 1+4-2/3, 1+4*2-3, 1+4*2/3, 1+4/2-3, 1+4/2*3, 1-4+2*3, 1-4+2/3, 1-4*2+3, 1-4*2/3, 1-4/2+3, 1-4/2*3, 1*4+2-3, 1*4+2/3, 1*4-2+3, 1*4-2/3, 1*4/2+3, 1*4/2-3, 1/4+2-3, 1/4+2*3, 1/4-2+3, 1/4-2*3, 1/4*2+3, 1/4*2-3, 1+4-3*2, 1+4-3/2, 1+4*3-2, 1+4*3/2, 1+4/3-2, 1+4/3*2, 1-4+3*2, 1-4+3/2, 1-4*3+2, 1-4*3/2, 1-4/3+2, 1-4/3*2, 1*4+3-2, 1*4+3/2, 1*4-3+2, 1*4-3/2, 1*4/3+2, 1*4/3-2, 1/4+3-2, 1/4+3*2, 1/4-3+2, 1/4-3*2, 1/4*3+2, 1/4*3-2, 2+1-3*4, 2+1-3/4, 2+1*3-4, 2+1*3/4, 2+1/3-4, 2+1/3*4, 2-1+3*4, 2-1+3/4, 2-1*3+4, 2-1*3/4, 2-1/3+4, 2-1/3*4, 2*1+3-4, 2*1+3/4, 2*1-3+4, 2*1-3/4, 2*1/3+4, 2*1/3-4, 2/1+3-4, 2/1+3*4, 2/1-3+4, 2/1-3*4, 2/1*3+4, 2/1*3-4, 2+1-4*3, 2+1-4/3, 2+1*4-3, 2+1*4/3, 2+1/4-3, 2+1/4*3, 2-1+4*3, 2-1+4/3, 2-1*4+3, 2-1*4/3, 2-1/4+3, 2-1/4*3, 2*1+4-3, 2*1+4/3, 2*1-4+3, 2*1-4/3, 2*1/4+3, 2*1/4-3, 2/1+4-3, 2/1+4*3, 2/1-4+3, 2/1-4*3, 2/1*4+3, 2/1*4-3, 2+3-1*4, 2+3-1/4, 2+3*1-4, 2+3*1/4, 2+3/1-4, 2+3/1*4, 2-3+1*4, 2-3+1/4, 2-3*1+4, 2-3*1/4, 2-3/1+4, 2-3/1*4, 2*3+1-4, 2*3+1/4, 2*3-1+4, 2*3-1/4, 2*3/1+4, 2*3/1-4, 2/3+1-4, 2/3+1*4, 2/3-1+4, 2/3-1*4, 2/3*1+4, 2/3*1-4, 2+3-4*1, 2+3-4/1, 2+3*4-1, 2+3*4/1, 2+3/4-1, 2+3/4*1, 2-3+4*1, 2-3+4/1, 2-3*4+1, 2-3*4/1, 2-3/4+1, 2-3/4*1, 2*3+4-1, 2*3+4/1, 2*3-4+1, 2*3-4/1, 2*3/4+1, 2*3/4-1, 2/3+4-1, 2/3+4*1, 2/3-4+1, 2/3-4*1, 2/3*4+1, 2/3*4-1, 2+4-1*3, 2+4-1/3, 2+4*1-3, 2+4*1/3, 2+4/1-3, 2+4/1*3, 2-4+1*3, 2-4+1/3, 2-4*1+3, 2-4*1/3, 2-4/1+3, 2-4/1*3, 2*4+1-3, 2*4+1/3, 2*4-1+3, 2*4-1/3, 2*4/1+3, 2*4/1-3, 2/4+1-3, 2/4+1*3, 2/4-1+3, 2/4-1*3, 2/4*1+3, 2/4*1-3, 2+4-3*1, 2+4-3/1, 2+4*3-1, 2+4*3/1, 2+4/3-1, 2+4/3*1, 2-4+3*1, 2-4+3/1, 2-4*3+1, 2-4*3/1, 2-4/3+1, 2-4/3*1, 2*4+3-1, 2*4+3/1, 2*4-3+1, 2*4-3/1, 2*4/3+1, 2*4/3-1, 2/4+3-1, 2/4+3*1, 2/4-3+1, 2/4-3*1, 2/4*3+1, 2/4*3-1, 3+1-2*4, 3+1-2/4, 3+1*2-4, 3+1*2/4, 3+1/2-4, 3+1/2*4, 3-1+2*4, 3-1+2/4, 3-1*2+4, 3-1*2/4, 3-1/2+4, 3-1/2*4, 3*1+2-4, 3*1+2/4, 3*1-2+4, 3*1-2/4, 3*1/2+4, 3*1/2-4, 3/1+2-4, 3/1+2*4, 3/1-2+4, 3/1-2*4, 3/1*2+4, 3/1*2-4, 3+1-4*2, 3+1-4/2, 3+1*4-2, 3+1*4/2, 3+1/4-2, 3+1/4*2, 3-1+4*2, 3-1+4/2, 3-1*4+2, 3-1*4/2, 3-1/4+2, 3-1/4*2, 3*1+4-2, 3*1+4/2, 3*1-4+2, 3*1-4/2, 3*1/4+2, 3*1/4-2, 3/1+4-2, 3/1+4*2, 3/1-4+2, 3/1-4*2, 3/1*4+2, 3/1*4-2, 3+2-1*4, 3+2-1/4, 3+2*1-4, 3+2*1/4, 3+2/1-4, 3+2/1*4, 3-2+1*4, 3-2+1/4, 3-2*1+4, 3-2*1/4, 3-2/1+4, 3-2/1*4, 3*2+1-4, 3*2+1/4, 3*2-1+4, 3*2-1/4, 3*2/1+4, 3*2/1-4, 3/2+1-4, 3/2+1*4, 3/2-1+4, 3/2-1*4, 3/2*1+4, 3/2*1-4, 3+2-4*1, 3+2-4/1, 3+2*4-1, 3+2*4/1, 3+2/4-1, 3+2/4*1, 3-2+4*1, 3-2+4/1, 3-2*4+1, 3-2*4/1, 3-2/4+1, 3-2/4*1, 3*2+4-1, 3*2+4/1, 3*2-4+1, 3*2-4/1, 3*2/4+1, 3*2/4-1, 3/2+4-1, 3/2+4*1, 3/2-4+1, 3/2-4*1, 3/2*4+1, 3/2*4-1, 3+4-1*2, 3+4-1/2, 3+4*1-2, 3+4*1/2, 3+4/1-2, 3+4/1*2, 3-4+1*2, 3-4+1/2, 3-4*1+2, 3-4*1/2, 3-4/1+2, 3-4/1*2, 3*4+1-2, 3*4+1/2, 3*4-1+2, 3*4-1/2, 3*4/1+2, 3*4/1-2, 3/4+1-2, 3/4+1*2, 3/4-1+2, 3/4-1*2, 3/4*1+2, 3/4*1-2, 3+4-2*1, 3+4-2/1, 3+4*2-1, 3+4*2/1, 3+4/2-1, 3+4/2*1, 3-4+2*1, 3-4+2/1, 3-4*2+1, 3-4*2/1, 3-4/2+1, 3-4/2*1, 3*4+2-1, 3*4+2/1, 3*4-2+1, 3*4-2/1, 3*4/2+1, 3*4/2-1, 3/4+2-1, 3/4+2*1, 3/4-2+1, 3/4-2*1, 3/4*2+1, 3/4*2-1, 4+1-2*3, 4+1-2/3, 4+1*2-3, 4+1*2/3, 4+1/2-3, 4+1/2*3, 4-1+2*3, 4-1+2/3, 4-1*2+3, 4-1*2/3, 4-1/2+3, 4-1/2*3, 4*1+2-3, 4*1+2/3, 4*1-2+3, 4*1-2/3, 4*1/2+3, 4*1/2-3, 4/1+2-3, 4/1+2*3, 4/1-2+3, 4/1-2*3, 4/1*2+3, 4/1*2-3, 4+1-3*2, 4+1-3/2, 4+1*3-2, 4+1*3/2, 4+1/3-2, 4+1/3*2, 4-1+3*2, 4-1+3/2, 4-1*3+2, 4-1*3/2, 4-1/3+2, 4-1/3*2, 4*1+3-2, 4*1+3/2, 4*1-3+2, 4*1-3/2, 4*1/3+2, 4*1/3-2, 4/1+3-2, 4/1+3*2, 4/1-3+2, 4/1-3*2, 4/1*3+2, 4/1*3-2, 4+2-1*3, 4+2-1/3, 4+2*1-3, 4+2*1/3, 4+2/1-3, 4+2/1*3, 4-2+1*3, 4-2+1/3, 4-2*1+3, 4-2*1/3, 4-2/1+3, 4-2/1*3, 4*2+1-3, 4*2+1/3, 4*2-1+3, 4*2-1/3, 4*2/1+3, 4*2/1-3, 4/2+1-3, 4/2+1*3, 4/2-1+3, 4/2-1*3, 4/2*1+3, 4/2*1-3, 4+2-3*1, 4+2-3/1, 4+2*3-1, 4+2*3/1, 4+2/3-1, 4+2/3*1, 4-2+3*1, 4-2+3/1, 4-2*3+1, 4-2*3/1, 4-2/3+1, 4-2/3*1, 4*2+3-1, 4*2+3/1, 4*2-3+1, 4*2-3/1, 4*2/3+1, 4*2/3-1, 4/2+3-1, 4/2+3*1, 4/2-3+1, 4/2-3*1, 4/2*3+1, 4/2*3-1, 4+3-1*2, 4+3-1/2, 4+3*1-2, 4+3*1/2, 4+3/1-2, 4+3/1*2, 4-3+1*2, 4-3+1/2, 4-3*1+2, 4-3*1/2, 4-3/1+2, 4-3/1*2, 4*3+1-2, 4*3+1/2, 4*3-1+2, 4*3-1/2, 4*3/1+2, 4*3/1-2, 4/3+1-2, 4/3+1*2, 4/3-1+2, 4/3-1*2, 4/3*1+2, 4/3*1-2, 4+3-2*1, 4+3-2/1, 4+3*2-1, 4+3*2/1, 4+3/2-1, 4+3/2*1, 4-3+2*1, 4-3+2/1, 4-3*2+1, 4-3*2/1, 4-3/2+1, 4-3/2*1, 4*3+2-1, 4*3+2/1, 4*3-2+1, 4*3-2/1, 4*3/2+1, 4*3/2-1, 4/3+2-1, 4/3+2*1, 4/3-2+1, 4/3-2*1, 4/3*2+1, 4/3*2-1
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution consumes a list of values and thus applies operations on the order with which arguments are given, as an alternative to normal arithmetic evaluation order. For example, `1 + 3 + 5 + 7`, would be `(((1 + 3) +5) + 7)`. However, it takes all possible permutations of values, so all possibilities are listed anyway.
It also allows one to give any operations as parameters, even lambda expressions.

I use itertools.

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
from itertools import permutations
from itertools import product
from itertools import chain
```

To display all expressions we call:

```
def list_all(operations, values):
    if len(values) == 1:
        return values
    permutes = []
    ops = []
    expressions = []
    # for 4 values we want combinations with 2, 3 and 4 values.
    for subset in range(2, len(values)+1):
        # One could use combinations instead of permutations if all ops
        # where know to be transitive.
        permutes.append(list(permutations(values, subset)))
        ops.append(list(combinations_with_replacement(operations, subset - 1)))
    for o, v in zip(ops, permutes):
        expressions.append(list(itertools.product(o, v)))
    return expressions
```

And to evaluate them, `execute` takes the output of `list_all`:

```
def execute(expressions):
    results = []
    # Flatten all expressions into a single iterator
    for ops, arguments in chain.from_iterable(expressions):
        oplist = list(ops)
        arglist = list(arguments)
        res = oplist.pop(0)(arglist.pop(0), arglist.pop(0))
        while len(arglist) > 0:
            res = oplist.pop(0)(res, arglist.pop(0))
        results.append(res)
    return results
```

Example usage:

```
from operator import add
from operator import sub
import pprint
expressions = list_all([add, sub, lambda x,y : sqrt(x*x + y*y)], [1, 2, 3, 4])
results = execute(expressions)

# Display list with operators, arguments and results.
pprint.pprint(zip(chain.from_iterable(expressions), results))
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the simpler and cleaner code to achieve this using [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) and [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html).

Also check regarding why not to use `eval`: [Is using eval in Python a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1832957/2063361)

```
from itertools import product, combinations, chain
from operator import add, sub, mul, div, mod, floordiv

my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 0]
my_operations = {'+': add, '-': sub, '/': div, '*': mul, '%': mod, '//': floordiv}

for nums, action in chain(product([i for i in combinations(my_list, 2)], my_operations)):
    try:
        result = my_operations[action](nums[0], nums[1])
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        result = 'infinite'
    finally:
        print '{} {} {} = {}'.format(nums[0], action, nums[1], result)
```

Below is the output of above code:

```
1 // 2 = 0
1 % 2 = 1
1 + 2 = 3
1 * 2 = 2
1 - 2 = -1
1 / 2 = 0
1 // 3 = 0
1 % 3 = 1
1 + 3 = 4
1 * 3 = 3
1 - 3 = -2
1 / 3 = 0
1 // 4 = 0
1 % 4 = 1
1 + 4 = 5
1 * 4 = 4
1 - 4 = -3
1 / 4 = 0
1 // 0 = infinite
1 % 0 = infinite
1 + 0 = 1
1 * 0 = 0
1 - 0 = 1
1 / 0 = infinite
2 // 3 = 0
2 % 3 = 2
2 + 3 = 5
2 * 3 = 6
2 - 3 = -1
2 / 3 = 0
2 // 4 = 0
2 % 4 = 2
2 + 4 = 6
2 * 4 = 8
2 - 4 = -2
2 / 4 = 0
2 // 0 = infinite
2 % 0 = infinite
2 + 0 = 2
2 * 0 = 0
2 - 0 = 2
2 / 0 = infinite
3 // 4 = 0
3 % 4 = 3
3 + 4 = 7
3 * 4 = 12
3 - 4 = -1
3 / 4 = 0
3 // 0 = infinite
3 % 0 = infinite
3 + 0 = 3
3 * 0 = 0
3 - 0 = 3
3 / 0 = infinite
4 // 0 = infinite
4 % 0 = infinite
4 + 0 = 4
4 * 0 = 0
4 - 0 = 4
4 / 0 = infinite
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with 3 numbers, here's couple lines from output: `1 - 2 * 3 = -4`, `1 + 2 - 4 = 7`.

Comment: Now it seems to have issues with operator precedence: `1 + 2 * 3 = 9`

Comment: This solution outputs incorrect results, and is barely readable.